# How to extract and save audio from a .mp4 file

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am having a bit of trouble saving an audio file of a .mp4 file. The following code does not seem to be working.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *audioPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"soundOneNew.m4a"];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:full_url options:nil];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
CMTime vocalStartMarker = kCMTimeZero;
CMTime vocalEndMarker = exportSession.asset.duration;
CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(vocalStartMarker, vocalEndMarker);

//supported file types
NSArray *supportedTypeArray = exportSession.supportedFileTypes;

for (NSString *str in supportedTypeArray){
    NSLog(@"Supported file types  : %@",str);
}

exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:audioPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:audioPath error:nil];
}
NSLog(@"Audio Path %@", audioPath);
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed) {
        NSLog(@"Audio export failed");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"AudioLocation : %@",audioPath);
    }
}];
```

At the end of the execution I won't be getting an audio file in the specified directory.

Comment: do you get an error (e.g. "Audio export failed"?)? You're not actually listing out the "`error`" property of `exportSession`when things fail.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I am getting this error : Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x10d5e4c10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media.}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write a video file to an audio file.  Either read the audio track from the source video file and write it out using `AVAssetReader` + `AVAssetWriter`, or instead create an `AVMutableComposition` with the audio track from the source video inserted into an `AVMutableCompositionTrack` and then use the export session as you have it set up there, but with the composition as the asset.